# Can I use rsync to move a list of files in different directories to a remote sever without logging in more than once?

Tags: ssh, rsync, backup, remote

So, I'm trying to write a script to back up some various configuration files with my ssh fileserver, but I'm not sure the best way to go about this. It would be nice if I could just fill a file with absolute file paths for both machines and directly do this with parallel or something. [Parallel has a script that works for an individual directory](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Parallelizing-rsync), but I want to expand this to multiple locations.

For example:

```
/home/$USER/.bashrc --> remoteuser@remoteIP:/home/remoteuser/backup/.bashrc
/home/$USER/.config/i3/config --> remoteuser@remoteIP:/home/remoteuser/backup/.config/i3/config
```

for a multitude of files as well as going in the reverse direction if the server actually has a more recent copy.

```
remoteuser@remoteIP:/home/remoteuser/backup/.bashrc --> /home/$USER/.bashrc
```

I could effectively do this for one file using these two commands, but I'd have to log in twice.

```
rsync -vrut -e 'ssh -p portnumber' /home/$USER/.bashrc remoteuser@remoteIP:/home/remoteuser/backup/.bashrc

rsync -vrut -e 'ssh -p portnumber' remoteuser@remoteIP:/home/remoteuser/backup/.bashrc /home/$USER/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first case, rsync is perfectly happy to accept multiple source operands and with [the `-R`/`--relative` option will preserve their paths](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), so

```
rsync -R backup/.bashrc backup/.config/i3/config dest:/home/remoteuser
```

should sort you out. The `--no-implied-dirs` option can be used with it to skip shared paths when you have more complicated structures.

> ```
> -R, --relative              use relative path names
>     --no-implied-dirs       don't send implied dirs with --relative
> ```

For the reverse direction you can do the same with multiple remote sources and rsync should be clever enough not to make separate connections to the same server.

Sometimes it can be easier if you're doing this a lot to make a fake directory structure full of symlinks that includes just the files you want and use the -L option with a single source.

On the other hand, it's *always* directional: you can't have a single command that makes both sides have the newest version, so that will require two commands. You could use a shared SSH control socket to run them both over the same SSH connection, so that there's only one actual login - see `ControlMaster` and others in the ssh config documentation.